# Parametric union in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a generic way of specifying a union parametrically? I'm looking for a way of generically specifying something like:

```
type U<K> = T<K1> | T<K2> | ... | T<Kn> // Where K === (K1 | ... | Kn)
```

**Note**: I'm dealing with a case where `T<U | V> !== T<U> | T<V>`. (Sort of the opposite of [#14107](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) and [#16644](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16644)

**Edit**: I've discovered the following pattern when `K` is a union of string literals:

```
type U<K> = {[key in K]: T<key>}[K]
```

but doesn't play nicely with type inference if I try to use it as a function argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript 2.8 provides another way of accomplishing this distribution using [conditional types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/03/27/announcing-typescript-2-8/#conditional-types). An example from the release announcement:

```
type Foo<T> = T extends any ? T[] : never;

/**
 * Foo distributes on 'string | number' to the type
 *
 *    (string extends any ? string[] : never) |
 *    (number extends any ? number[] : never)
 * 
 * which boils down to
 *
 *    string[] | number[]
 */
type Bar = Foo<string | number>;
```